# How to assert method call order with Python Mock?

Tags: python, mocking

Suppose I have a python function

```
def func(self):
    self.method_1()
    self.method_2()
```

How can I write an unit test that can assert method_1 is called before method_2?

```
@mock.patch(method_1)
@mock.patch(method_2)
def test_call_order(method_2_mock, method_1_mock):
     # Test the order
```

Comment: I think you're missing the word *"before"*... Have you read e.g. http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#tracking-order-of-calls-and-less-verbose-call-assertions?

Answer (score 20):

Your case is a slight variation of [Python Unit Testing with two mock objects, how to verify call-order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29749193/4101725). What you should do is set `method_2_mock`, `method_1_mock` as children of one new mock object and then ask for `mock_calls` attribute or use `assert_has_calls`:

```
@mock.patch(method_1)
@mock.patch(method_2)
def test_call_order(method_2_mock, method_1_mock):
    mock_parent = Mock()
    mock_parent.m1, mock_parent.m2 = method_1_mock, method_2_mock
    <test code>
    """Check if method 1 is called before method 2"""
    mock_parent.assert_has_calls([call.m1(), call.m2()])
```

There are lot of details omitted in this code like call arguments. Take a look to [`call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#call) and the very useful [`ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#call) helper.

**ATTENTION**
This is valid just for `unitetest.mock` in python3. For python 2.7 and mock 1.0.1 you should use `attach_mock` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create a simple list and append each mock to it through `side_effect`.

```
@mock.patch(method_1)
@mock.patch(method_2)
def test_call_order(method_2_mock, method_1_mock):
    call_order = []
    method_1_mock.side_effect = lambda *a, **kw: call_order.append(method_1_mock)
    method_2_mock.side_effect = lambda *a, **kw: call_order.append(method_2_mock)
    # Run test code...
    assert call_order == [method_1_mock, method_2_mock]
```

Each time the method is called, the `side_effect` lambda function is called. Since lists are ordered, this is a clean way to check the call order of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on the second approach, by Chris Collett.

Using `side_effect` like that makes the call return None. This is a problem if you need the mock method to return a value. A simple solution is to use a helper function:

```
call_order = []

def log_ret(func, ret_val):
    call_order.append(func)
    return ret_val

method_1_mock.side_effect = lambda *a, **kw: log_ret(method_1_mock, 'return_value_1')
method_2_mock.side_effect = lambda *a, **kw: log_ret(method_2_mock, 'return_value_2')
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For me Michele d'Amico's answer does not work.

I have found the following way to in doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#tracking-order-of-calls-and-less-verbose-call-assertions

```
@mock.patch(method_1)
@mock.patch(method_2)
def test_call_order(method_2_mock, method_1_mock):
    manager = Mock()
    manager.attach_mock(method_1_mock, 'method_1_mock')
    manager.attach_mock(method_2_mock, 'method_2_mock')

    #call func()
    
    """Check if method 1 is called before method 2"""
    manager.assert_has_calls([call.method_1_mock(), call.method_2_mock()])
```