# Cannot use attach_mock with an autospec function mock

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

Library module:

```
# mod.py
def foo():
    bar1("arg1")
    bar2("arg2x", "arg2y")

def bar1(x):
    pass

def bar2(x, y):
    pass
```

Test module:

```
# test_mod.py
from mod import foo

def test_foo(mocker):
    mock = mocker.MagicMock()
    mock.attach_mock(mocker.patch("mod.bar1"), "b1")
    mock.attach_mock(mocker.patch("mod.bar2", autospec=True), "b2")
    foo()
    mock.assert_has_calls(
        [
            mocker.call.b1("arg1"),
            mocker.call.b2("arg2x", "arg2y"),
        ]
    )
```

<sub>The `mocker` fixture is from [`pytest-mock`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) plugin. Execute the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with `python -m pytest`.</sub>

This test fails for [weird](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L692-L726) [reasons](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L325-L329).

```
E       AssertionError: Calls not found.
E       Expected: [call.b1('arg1'), call.b2('arg2x', 'arg2y')]
E       Actual: [call.b1('arg1')]
```

Without the [autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#auto-speccing) it works. Does using autospec break the `attach_mock` feature? How should the test for `foo` assert on the **order and args** of the calls to dependencies `bar1` and `bar2` **without losing their autospec**?

Comment: Hmm, looks like `mocker.patch("mod.bar2", autospec=True)` didn't patch the function at all - can you check that?

Comment: @hoefling  What makes you say that?  It does mock it out - but the autospec makes the mock look a lot more like the original than usual.  Put an `1/0` inside the body of `bar2` if you want to convince yourself of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a bug in Python. It got fixed in late 2019, patched versions:

- [Python 3.8.2+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-8-2-release-candidate-1)
- [Python 3.7.5+](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-7-5-release-candidate-1)

The test in original post is now passing on a fixed version. No backport for Python 3.6, which is [security only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0494/) now so will remain bugged forever.

These are the related PRs and issue tracker links:

***[bpo-21478](https://bugs.python.org/issue21478)*: [Autospec functions should propagate mock calls to parent](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/11273)**

***[bpo-21478](https://bugs.python.org/issue21478)*: [Record calls to parent when autospecced objects are used as child with `attach_mock`](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/14688)**

***[bpo-38473](https://bugs.python.org/issue38473)*: [Handle autospecced functions and methods used with `attach_mock`](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/16784)**

Patch by Karthikeyan Singaravelan.