# Checking call order with pytest-mock

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

In the code snippet shown below I would like to test the function call order in the `run()` function, i.e, `f_3` is called after `f_2` that is called after `f_1`:

```
class TestMock:

    def f_1(self) -> None:
        pass

    def f_2(self) -> None:
        pass

    def f_3(self) -> None:
        pass

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.f_1()
        self.f_2()
        self.f_3()
```

Is there any way to do this using `pytest-mock`? I have tried to mock the `f_1`, `f_2`, and `f_3` functions in my test file and use `assert_has_calls` with `any_order=False`, however, without success.

Thanks in advance for any help or hints!

Best,
Alexey

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking call order across multiple mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677280/checking-call-order-across-multiple-mocks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track there with `any_order=False`, you just need to know about the [`attach_mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.attach_mock) feature:

```
import yourmodule

def test_something(mocker):
    mock = mocker.MagicMock()
    mock.attach_mock(mocker.patch("yourmodule.TestMock.f_1"), "f_1")
    mock.attach_mock(mocker.patch("yourmodule.TestMock.f_2"), "f_2")
    mock.attach_mock(mocker.patch("yourmodule.TestMock.f_3"), "f_3")
    yourinstance = yourmodule.TestMock()
    yourinstance.run()
    mock.assert_has_calls(
        [
            mocker.call.f_1(),
            mocker.call.f_2(),
            mocker.call.f_3(),
        ],
        any_order=False,
    )
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, it helped me further! Please check my answer and the revised code below, I have the follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched completely to `unittest.mock` and have the following working code now:

```
@mock.patch('.'.join([__name__, 'TestMock', 'f_3']))
@mock.patch('.'.join([__name__, 'TestMock', 'f_2']))
@mock.patch('.'.join([__name__, 'TestMock', 'f_1']))
def test_order_2(f_1: mock.NonCallableMock,
                 f_2: mock.NonCallableMock,
                 f_3: mock.NonCallableMock) -> None:
    manager = mock.Mock()
    manager.attach_mock(f_1, 'f_1')
    manager.attach_mock(f_2, 'f_2')
    manager.attach_mock(f_3, 'f_3')

    obj = TestMock()
    obj.run()

    manager.assert_has_calls([mock.call.f_1,
                              mock.call.f_2,
                              mock.call.f_3], any_order=False)
```

here comes the **question**: I don't really understand the meaning behind attribute names so, they are mandatory, but the only reasonable names to me are the function names themselves... I have modified the attribute names as follows:

```
@mock.patch('.'.join([__name__, 'TestMock', 'f_3']))
@mock.patch('.'.join([__name__, 'TestMock', 'f_2']))
@mock.patch('.'.join([__name__, 'TestMock', 'f_1']))
def test_order_1(f_1: mock.NonCallableMock,
                 f_2: mock.NonCallableMock,
                 f_3: mock.NonCallableMock) -> None:
    manager = mock.Mock()
    manager.attach_mock(f_1, f_1._extract_mock_name())
    manager.attach_mock(f_2, f_2._extract_mock_name())
    manager.attach_mock(f_3, f_3._extract_mock_name())

    obj = TestMock()
    obj.run()

    manager.assert_has_calls([mock.call.f_1,
                              mock.call.f_2,
                              mock.call.f_3], any_order=False)
```

would be great to hear your opinion on this!

by the way, why `f_*` mock objects are of the `mock.NonCallableMoc` type? I would expect they are replaced by dummy functions (`Collable`)...

Thanks in advance for the help again!

Best,
Alexey